# Concatenating a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following two JavaScript function:

**JS 1**

```
$( ".show-more" ).click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( this ).next().slideToggle( "fast", function() {
  });
  $( this ).toggleClass("show-more-rotate");
});
```

**JS 2**

```
$( ".show-more-section" ).click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( this ).next().slideToggle( "fast", function() {
  });
  $( this ).toggleClass("show-more-section-rotate");
});
```

Is there a way to concatenate the two functions into one? I tried the following, but the functionality seems to only be working for the last listed element:

**JS - Failed attemp at concatenating**

```
$( ".show-more, .show-more-section" ).click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( this ).next().slideToggle( "fast", function() {
  });
  $( this ).toggleClass("show-more-rotate, show-more-section-rotate");
});
```

Comment: You can create the callback function and reference it

Comment: Remove comma from toggleClass

Comment: Shouldn't your call to `toggleClass()` be part of the callback passed to `slideToggle()` instead of running sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
 $(".show-more, .show-more-section").on('click', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).next().slideToggle("fast", function () {});
   if($(this).is('.show-more'))
   {
    $(this).toggleClass("show-more-rotate");       
   }else
   {
    $(this).toggleClass("show-more-section-rotate");
   }
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guzzjty1/11/)

Answer (score 2):

See comments inline:

```
// bind event on both the elements
$(".show-more, .show-more-section").on('click', function (event) {
//                                                        ^^^^^^ Add this
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast", function () {});
    $(this).toggleClass("show-more-rotate show-more-section-rotate");
    // Remove `,` from toggleClass
});
```

**EDIT**

You can also chain the methods as:

```
$(this).toggleClass("show-more-rotate show-more-section-rotate")
    .next().slideToggle("fast", function () {});
```

**Update**

If you want to toggle class after slideToggle is completed:

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.next().slideToggle("fast", function () {
    $this.toggleClass("show-more-rotate show-more-section-rotate")
});
```

Comment: The original answer you gave seems to only be targeting and working for `.show-more-section` and `.show-more-section-rotate`, therefore only the last listed elements.

Comment: @JulianSamarjiev What are you saying?

Comment: @Tushar I am getting the same result as the code I listed under my failed attempt (only the second class' are getting targeted), and yes I did remove the comma :)

Comment: @JulianSamarjiev Please create `jsfiddle` for this

Answer (score 1):

You can create the handler function and can reuse it in the click handler

```
$( ".show-more" ).click(showMoreClickHandler);

$( ".show-more-section" ).click(showMoreClickHandler);

function showMoreClickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( this ).next().slideToggle( "fast", function() {});
    $( this ).toggleClass("");
}
```

For toggle class, you can add `data-toggle-class` attribute in HTML and can read the value and perform toggling.

I hope, `show-more-rotate` and `show-more-section-rotate` should be applied on it's respective element not on the other.

Comment: You are forgetting one class to toggle

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma in the toggleClass:

```
$(".show-more, .show-more-section").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast", function () {
    });
    $(this).toggleClass("show-more-rotate show-more-section-rotate");
});
```